# nodejs oracledb I'm getting the following error when I have executed my code

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-modules

I'm getting the following error when I have executed my code.
Can anyone help me with it?

```
//error from cmd
D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database>node oracledbSample.js
D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:38 throw err;
Error: \\?\D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:689:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)`enter code here` at   Module.require (module.js:604:17)  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:35:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
```

Comment: var oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "user",
    password      : "pass",
    connectString : "localhost/1521/XE"
  },
  function(err, connection)
  {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    } else {
    logger.loud("Connection successful!");
    }
});

Comment: The above is the code I wrote.

Comment: Can you please add Node Version and Windows Version (incl. Bits)?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this error occurs if you have either a mix of 32 and 64 bit binaries, or you don't have Oracle client libraries installed, or you are using Oracle Instant Client and don't have the correct VS Redistributable installed.

Make sure that Node.js and Oracle Instant Client are both 32-bit or are both 64-bit.  Check the Instant Client download page for the version & links to the VS Redistributable required.

I believe you are using node-oracledb v1.  Try updating to v2 since the startup errors messages will give a lot more information.